# How to display a website's popup on webview?

Tags: c#, webview, xamarin.forms, popup, cross-platform

On UWP: webview can auto display a popup when navigated to a website. exp: http://loribeauty1.ddns.eagleeyes.tw:80/Login.cgi
Like this image: https://ibb.co/6bHjztm
On iOS and Android: webview don't display this popup like UWP.
Do have a option to enable it?

Comment: This is called HTTP basic authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking for the Android-side: your application needs to override [`WebViewClient#onReceivedHttpAuthRequest()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). When this is called, your app must make its own pop-up UI to receive user credentials, and pass these back to the WebView via [`HttpAuthHandler#proceed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/HttpAuthHandler.html#proceed(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

I'm not as familiar with the iOS side, but I expect it needs a similar solution.